How to chuck JSON output efficiently to Azure Log Analytics workspace
I have data (650k rows) which i want to store using the Send data to Azure Log Analytics workspace module.
this is my workflow:

but i get this error:
    "message": "The response is not in a JSON format.",
    "innerError": "The page was not displayed because the request entity is too large."

when i send 20 rows worth of data it works.
I believe somewhere in the 650k rows a string breaks the json causing it to give me this error.
I believe Advanced Hunting is only giving me ~95k rows as an output, though 650k rows exist. maybe i have to structure it to give me 50k rows at a time and send that through.
whats the most efficient way to send this data in chucks using logic apps?

Here's a possible solution.

Gather what the max length of the data is:


Store this as a variable


Initialize a variable which is how many chunks we want. here I've split the total length by 10,000 . this is the number of chunks we wan.t


next we create an array of indexes, that is the length of the chunks i.e ([1,2,3,4,5,etc]). length(variables('numberArray')) and add(variables('lengthofarray'),1)


Now for every index in the array we send a chunk of data from the table.
the between statement has sub(mul(int(items('send_logs_to_LAW')),10000),10000) and mul(int(items('send_logs_to_LAW')),10000), this allows us to read only 10,000 rows and send 10,000 rows so we dont hit the limit on the send data module.



This is a solution that utilizes logic apps. However, there may be a better solution with DCR rules?
